# I mistakenly sent my bitcoin to a banned address. Please how can I get my bitcoin back?

Tags: transactions

MISTAKENLY SENT BTC TO A BANNED ADDRESS

how can I get my btc back that was mistakenly sent to a banned address

Comment: There is no such thing as a "banned address" in Bitcoin. You'll need to clarify what you did, what you expected to see, what you saw instead, and which software or websites are involved.

Comment: What I mean is that I mistakenly sent my bitcoin from my paxful account to another paxful account that have been banned......how can I get my bitcoin back to my paxful account

Comment: You should ask paxful. Nothing anyone else can do about this.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** based on your clarification, you were not asking about a "bitcoin address", but rather a "paxful account" -- two totally different things.  You will need to contact paxful to see what they can do.

---

Previous answer:

If you send bitcoins to ANY address for which you do not have the private key, then you no longer control that bitcoin.  It is owned by someone else (or lost) at that point.

If you know the owner of the address you can *ask* them to please send them to you, but this will obviously not help if they are criminals.  If you were scammed (tricked into sending bitcoin to someone fraudulently) -- then you can report it to [a website like this](https://bitcoinwhoswho.com/scams) (to help others) and / or the police.

**Note:** as mentioned by Pieter -- there is no such thing as a "banned address" in Bitcoin.  Any address that has the correct format is valid.